# How do I find datas by foreign key in sequelizejs?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I define these data (many to many relation) :

```
    exports.User = sequelize.define('user', {
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            unique: true,
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
    });


    exports.Project = sequelize.define('project', {
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            unique: true
        },
        description: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
    });

    exports.User.belongsToMany(exports.Project, {as: 'Projects', through: 'user_projects', foreignKey: 'userId'});
    exports.Project.belongsToMany(exports.User, {as: 'Users', through: 'user_projects', foreignKey: 'projectId'});
```

If I know a user id, how do query all projects in this user .
What I do now :

```
db.User.findById(userId).then(function (user) {
      user.getProjects().then(function(projects){
            //get
      });
 });
```

Could I just get projects by id ,not query twice?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do:

```
var query = {
  where: {id: userId},
  include: [
    {model: db.Project, as: 'Projects'}
  ]
}

db.User.findOne(query).
  then(function (user) {
    var projects = user.Projects
    ...
  });
```

Comment: In case this isn't clear, he is using eager loading. What this does behind the scenes is it JOINS the appropriate tables and processes the result into a nested structure, taking advantage of the fact that JS and JSON can handle non-tabular data